# Microsoft Edge chromium не отрисовывает график на основе c3.js

Tags: c3.js

Microsoft Edge chromium не отрисовывает график на основе c3.js. (не читает данные из файла).
Не работает секция:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
      url: '../data/c3_test.csv'
    }
```

Comment: Для начала попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу, а не относительный

Comment: не работает. Хотя если в коде по ссылке щелкнуть, то файл открывается.

Comment: А вы прямо из браузера страницу смотрите? Ну тогда не удивительно. Браузерам нельзя откуда угодно читать данные, иначе бы хакерские скрипты легко крали любую информацию с наших компьютеров :)

Comment: я смотрю данные из csv файла. До обновления edge все работало.

Comment: нашел на c3 сайте - Load a CSV or JSON file from a URL. Note that this will not work if loading via the "file://" protocol as the most browsers will block XMLHTTPRequests. Может это, тогда как исправить?